# Open source Database to ship with my application

Tags: database, open-source, embedded-database

I need open source database that I can ship with my commercial application.
It should not have any installation (i.e., no window service and no setup).

It can be single user database. It should work in Windows environment and used from Java code.

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I really like [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/).  You can use it with java via [SQLiteJDBC](http://www.zentus.com/sqlitejdbc/).  It is very good embedded database.  For Java, it might be easier to use [Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/) though.

Comment: Is Derby ready for prime time?

Answer (score 6):

You might also want to look at [HSQL](http://hsqldb.org/) and [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html), which are both open source embedded databases written in Java.

Answer (score 2):

[Firebird Embedded](http://www.firebirdsql.org/manual/fbmetasecur-embedded.html) - just needs couple of DLL files and you have full database in your hands. Have been using it for years.
[How to use it in Java](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq350/)

Answer (score 1):

Look into SQLite.  I haven't used it, but I've had apps that claimed to use it, and I couldn't tell the difference.

Answer (score 1):

How about [SQLite](http://www.zentus.com/sqlitejdbc/)?
It has good performance, and with one user you don't have to worry about concurrency.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle Berkeley DB: http://www.oracle.com/database/berkeley-db/index.html